# Leads and Ideas on Learning from disconnected data

Tags: data-mining, association-rules

Problem of learning patterns from disconnected data.
I have two independent discrete variables, D1 and D2, with information similar to tables in the images.

I do NOT have the broken down data for A+C and

I wish to infer rules such as:
    For ID 1, D1 = A && D2 == C will result in “more” Metric1 (with certain confidence)

[image]